# Formula for a skewed bell curve given mean, standard deviation, and median

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I have a large dataset of the income of various counties. I am given the median, mean, and standard deviation. I would like to do some analysis, but I would like to model the income these individual counties as skewed bell curves (feel free to offer a better idea). Thing is, I can't seem to find any good ways to derive the formula for a skewed bell curve given a mean, standard deviation, and median. I would be fine with even a decent approximation as I have been having trouble with deriving such a formula due to the error function.

Comment: Maybe you can get away with the [log normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) if the mean, median and variance satisfies certain equation close enough, but if not, you can always try the [generalised normal distibution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution#Version_2) or similar tweaks of the normal distribution.

Comment: log normal would not work since it is always positively skewed, but I'm looking at version 2 of the generalized distribution. This might work. EDIT: no, just realized it sort of just becomes zero fast if the shape is far from zero, which happens regularly in this data